# CentOS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, centos

So I have this VPS on CentOS. A few months ago, I installed apache2, mysql and some other stuff, to host a wordpress blog. Now, for some reason, the mysql service has shutdown, and I'm unable to restart it.

- "which mysql" returns "/usr/bin/mysql" seems to confirm it is indeed installed
- "/etc/init.d/mysql" returns "-bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory"
- "service mysql start" returns "-bash: service: command not found"
- Interchanging mysql for mysqld did not made any changes in those last two points
- Only log file related to mysql, in the /var/log folder is named mysqld.log.rpmsave and is empty

Thruthfully, I'm a programmer and I am utterly confused by this situation. Any idea?

-- EDIT --

Thanks for your answers guys. I tried Caleb and lain's suggestion and unfortunately `/sbin/service mysql start` or `/sbin/service mysqld start` returns me `unrecognized service`.

As for the result of `rpm -qa | grep mysql` : 
php-mysql-5.3.3-1.el5.remi
mysql-libs-5.1.53-1.el5.remi
mysql-5.1.53-1.el5.remi

remi being the repo where I found newer version of PHP (from 5.1.X to 5.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `remi` repo, you need `mysql-server`.  Try `yum install mysql-server`; you'll then be able to `chkconfig` and `service mysqld` to your heart's content.

If your remi repo isn't enabled by default, it'll be `yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql-server`; try that if you get a bunch of unresolved dependency messages.

Comment: Yep.  These other answers ignore the fact that you don't have the server installed.

Comment: To be fair, he edited the question to add the `rpm -qa` output.

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much the problem. For some freak reason, a repository conflict or something along those line, mysqld was uninstalled. Re-installed it and it's all good now.

Comment: Wow. I am a moron. Lucky I found your answer

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you somehow removed the server part of MySQL. `/usr/bin/mysql` is just the client part and doesn't have an entry in `/etc/init.d`. Can you post the output of `rpm -qa | grep mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS to start the mysql-server (mysqld) use the command

```
/sbin/service mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/sbin/service mysql restart`.

Looks like your shell, including exec paths and such, is pretty messed up, but you have been on the right track.

Comment: Yeah that is probably related to the installation and setup step I did a few months ago, quite rashly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the server installed.

```
# yum -y install mysql-server
# service mysqld start
```